# Make datatables with column search work for multiple tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this script for datatables which makes it possible to search in a table's columns. It works fine, but it won't work for multiple tables with the same class and structure.

What do I need to change in order to make it work for all tabels with the same class?

```
var doSearching = true,
  postsPerPage = 20,
  thisTable = $('.table');


if (doSearching) {
  var $tfoot = $('<tfoot>');
  var $search_tr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tfoot);
  thisTable.find('thead th').each(function() {
    var $title = $(this).text().toLowerCase(),
      input_html = [
        '<th>',
        '<input',
        ' type="text"',
        ' placeholder="Search ', $title, '"',
        '>',
        '</th>'
      ].join(""),
      $input = $(input_html);
    $search_tr.append($input);
  });
  $tfoot.insertAfter(thisTable.find('thead').first());
}


// DataTable
var table = thisTable.DataTable({
  ordering: true,
  paging: postsPerPage > 0 ? true : false,
  pageLength: postsPerPage,
  lengthChange: false,
  initComplete: function(settings) {
    if (!doSearching) {
      return;
    }

    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
    api.columns().every(function() {
      var that = this;
      $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
          that.search(this.value).draw();
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wn0mq2dc/4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to initialize each instance in isolation

Instead of `thisTable = $('.table');` try:

```
$('.table').each(function(){
   // thisTable is now single instance
   var thisTable = $(this);

   // initialize current instance with same code


});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but it didn't fix it. Datatables generally support multiple tables: `$('.table').DataTable();`

The issue is probably inside the `if (doSearching) {)` which makes the initialization break... The error is: `Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined`.

Comment: Yes it supports multiple tables but this approach would isolate the api for each one. You never specified what wasn't working properly in question, or errors

Comment: I appreciate your help. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8merz6yd/1/ - I implemented the loop but the second table is never initialized.